# restrict product page with product category 'x' WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, restriction

I wan't to restrict certain product pages from logged-out users or users with a specific role. The easiest way would probably be to check the category ID of the product page and if `current_user_can('')` than redirect to the main shop page.

However I don't really know where to start.. Should I add an action on `init`? And how do I check for the current page product ID?

I thought I could get some data with a `var_dump()` But that resulted in nothing. 
I did this:

```
add_action('init', 'get_all_post_meta');

function get_all_post_meta() {
    //$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
    global $post;
    var_dump('$post');
    $metavar = get_the_terms($post->ID);
    var_dump('$metavar');

}
```

But no results in my console.

Edit: I found my `var_dump()` was incorrect as it should be like `var_dump($post);` Continuing my quest now.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution so far, now I need to figure out how to remove a single product instead of them all.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'get_all_post_meta', 1 );

function get_all_post_meta() {

    global $post;
    $banned_cid = array(8);
    $current_cid = array();
    $metavar = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
    global $woocommerce;
    $redirect_url = 'http://www.example.nl/';


    if(current_user_can('subscriber') || current_user_can('manage_options')){}else if( is_product()){
        foreach ( $metavar as $term ) {
                        $cat_id .= $term->term_id.',';
                        array_push($current_cid, $term->term_id);
                    }
        var_dump($current_cid);

        $c = array_intersect($banned_cid, $current_cid);
            if (count($c) > 0) {    
                $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
                wp_redirect( $redirect_url, 302 );
                exit;
        }
    }
}
```